# Why doesn't Swing formWindowClosed work properly?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have a `SWING` form and when I close the application I want to save data to a text file.

This is the code generated by Swing which I cannot modify:

```
    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter()
    {
        public void windowClosed(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt)
        {
            formWindowClosed(evt);
        }
    });
```

Here is my custom implementation of `formWindowClosed`. The problem is that the app closes without executing formWindowClosed.

Isn't `formWindowClosed` the method where I want to put the code that gets executed before the app closes ?

`formWindoClosed` implementation:

```
private void formWindowClosed(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt)
{

    System.out.println("Message");
    brain.getBirou().getProbaRepo().WriteParticipantToTXT();
}
```

Comment: *"which I cannot modify:"*  Extract your testicles from your IDE.  (It has you 'by the balls'.)  An expansion of that concept.  1) This is only ever said by people using an IDE.  2) It is only people using the GUI editor of said IDE to 'write their code for them'.  3) An IDE in the hands of an experienced user places **no limits** on the code produced, even when using the GUI designer. 4) Yopur comment indicates that you don't know how to use the IDE, and it is therfore an impediment to actually getting the final code.

Comment: Well that is a good advice. But I am using Swing with Netbeans because all I need to do is create a simple app in 2h (exam) and it saves time.

Comment: *"it saves time."*  Really?  (checks watch)  Let's see how long it take you to sort *this* problem.  ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to execute code before the process exits, you have to set the default close operation to `WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` then in the listener method save your file and then call `System.exit(0);` when you're done.
Also "Swing" doesn't generate code by itself. Maybe you should write your GUI code for your self, by hand. Then of course you can modify *anything*.
You have to have the possibility to change exit behavior of your window, so setting it to dispose on close should help. Maybe you should look up where you can change it in your IDE. (Or just open it with a text editor...)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I think I've found my problem. I was trying to implement formWindowClose() but the one I needed was formWindowClosing() so that I can execute code just before the app closes.

Comment: @AndrewThompson ofc means of course. I will better write the long form for more clarity ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can use formWindowClosing instead.

To do this through the Netbeans IDE GUI Builder:
Go to Design view and right-click the [JFrame] inside the Navigator window. Go to events and select the event you want to add.

Remember to mark the frame as DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE in the defaultCloseOperation property.